# Store grive command output to variable in bash script

Tags: bash, grive

I am trying to create a script that syncs my computer with google drive using the [grive](https://github.com/vitalif/grive2) tool. I would like to store the output of the `grive` command to a bash variable, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Some googling has taught me that command outputs can be saved to variables using the following syntax:

`VARABLENAME=$(command)`

and the output can be later printed by

`echo ${VARIABLENAME}`

However, the grive command seems to be an exception to this because when I use this syntax, it still prints out the output in the terminal and the contents of the variable is empty.

How I can store the output of `grive` in a variable properly?

Comment: Perhaps it is going to STDERR..Run `VARABLENAME="$(command 2>&1)"` and then check with `echo "${VARIABLENAME}"`..

Comment: That did the trick! Can you please explain what that means? Also, resubmit it as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem was that `grive` command was outputting to the error stream, STDERR (File descriptor 2), which is normally used for passing error messages while the STDOUT (File descriptor 1) is used for showing actual (upon success) output of any program (strictly speaking).

I have not used `grive`, but according to your words the developer might have used STDERR only to show any messages from the command.

Now the command substitution you have used :

```
VARABLENAME=$(command)
```

will save the STDOUT of `command` to `VARABLENAME`, not STDERR. As a result the variable was empty and you were seeing messages on terminal.

I have suggested :

```
VARABLENAME="$(command 2>&1)"
```

this will save both the STDOUT and STDERR to the variable (in your case just STDERR as there is no STDOUT), So you would get desired result using `echo "${VARIABLENAME}"`.

Also as there is no STDOUT you can save just the STDERR to the variable (generalization, true for any such program) :

```
VARABLENAME="$(command 2>&1 >/dev/null)"
```

Comment: +1 however technically speaking if there's no `stdout` you don't need to redirect it, so that could be still `VARABLENAME="$(command 2>&1)"` without wasting a redirection ;) I see what you meant, but maybe it needs rephrasing, such as "If you want to save only `stderr` than you can [...]"

Comment: @kos Yeah..after thinking about that i have gone for generalization (taking no chances)..anyway clarified a bit more.. ;)

Comment: What I meant is that if there's no `stdout` (as in "Also as there is no STDOUT [...]" <- this is what I was referring to) then the command might be just `VARABLENAME="$(command 2>&1)"` without using another redirection, just like in the previous case; I tought maybe you wanted to address a different case such as "Also *if you don't want to store* STDOUT [...]"